# android.view.InflateException:Binary xml file Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.Xwalkview

Tags: android, crosswalk, android-jsinterface

I am trying to build hybrid app using xwalkview but continuosly getting this error. I have added crosswalk-webview-arm library and appcompat-v7 libarary and 2 jars. android-support-v4 jar and xwalk-core-library.jar. Removing any one of them is creating complie time error.

android_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.hcp_android.NewMainActivity" >


  <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView 
    android:id="@+id/webPage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     />
```

NewMainActivity.java

```
public class NewMainActivity extends Activity {
XWalkView xwalkview;
MediaPlayer ringtone;
AndroidJSInterface jSInterface;
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
int k = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    xwalkview=(XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.webPage);
    jSInterface = new AndroidJSInterface(this);
    xwalkview.addJavascriptInterface(jSInterface, "AndroidJSInterface");
    xwalkview.load("file:///android_asset/login.html", null);
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Elltz:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line  Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView

Comment: Could you share the version of Crosswalk and which toolchain you are using?

Comment: @SwagDevelopers have you solve ur problem?

Comment: I fixed this to change the version number in gradle file: implementation 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:23.53.589.4'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution:

Remember to ask for the needed permissions in your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the result of the conflict of the so library, in the productreading in build.gradle:

```
ndk {
      abiFilters "armeabi", "x86"
}
```